# How to show all data in Grid in Descending Order. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, backend

I'm getting data in Grid in Ascending Order But I want this data in Descending order how can I set this??? My `mycode_listing.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing_data_source</item>
           <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing_data_source</item>
       </item>
       <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_index_columns</item>
       <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
               <!-- <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Blog Post</item>
               <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
               <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item> -->
           </item>
       </item>
   </argument>
   <dataSource name="makeanoffer_listing_data_source">
       <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
           <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">makeanofferGridDataProvider</argument>
           <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing_data_source</argument>
           <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_id</argument>
           <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                   <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </argument>
   </dataSource>
   <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
       <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
       <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
       <filterSearch name="fulltext"/> <!--yha pr side wala jha pr full name likhna hoga -->
       <filters name="listing_filters">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_index_columns</item>
                   <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">storageConfig.storageConfig.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                       <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="filters" xsi:type="array"> <!--ye wo 2ra wala filter side me ha conform ni ha... whi ha Q k nechy nam b likha ha items ka -->
                           <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                               <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">storageConfig.storageConfig.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                       <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">storageConfig.storageConfig.makeanoffer_index_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </item>
               <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </filters>
       <massaction name="listing_massaction">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_index_columns.ids</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
           <action name="delete">
               <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                       <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                       <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="makeanoffer/index/massDelete"/>
                       <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                           <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </argument>
           </action>
       </massaction>
       <paging name="listing_paging"/>
   </listingToolbar>

   <columns name="makeanoffer_index_columns">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                   <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
               </item>
               <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_index_columns.ids</item>
                   <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                   <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="news/index/inlineEdit"/>
                       <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   </item>
               </item>
               <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_index_columns_editor</item>
                       <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                       <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                           <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_listing.makeanoffer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                       <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                       <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                   </item>
               </item>
           </item>
       </argument>
       <selectionsColumn name="ids">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="name">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="email">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>   
       <column name="pnumber">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone Number</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
```

Answer (score 4):

To display admin grid data in descending order to your custom module follow the **Magento_Sales** Because of Magento sales module display order data in descending order.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Find below code

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
        <settings>
            <filter>dateRange</filter>
            <dataType>date</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Purchase Date</label>
            <sorting>desc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

Magento sales order sorting data descending order ad Created_date see in above code. you can set sort order By ID, By Date etc...

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<column name="name">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
</column>
```

**You just need to add asc or desc sorting tab**

```
<item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
```

Comment: Where I need to add This??? can you please mention in above code??? I tried this earlier in every single column but it was not working for me

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Did I need to add this in every single column???

Comment: I am Not Sure but yes try this

Comment: Its not working

Comment: asc or desc ?????